# How to print value with a common key from two files but in a specific column in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a main file bla.tsv (FS=`\t`):

```
id hub fil plop
34  ji ji
54  jo jo
46  ja ja
```

And a info file hub.csv (FS=`,`):

```
34,fuse
46,fose
```

And I want to print the info of `hub.csv` into the column `hub` of `bla.tsv` like this:

```
id hub fil plop
34 fuse ji ji
54  jo jo
46 fose ja ja
```

I managed to print the correct info in the correct line but at the column after the last one:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,a[$1]}' FS="," hub.csv FS="\t" bla.tsv > result.tsv
```

How can I fill the second column of `bla.tsv` with the value found in `hub.csv` (if any)? Note that the structure of `bla.tsv` is already "correct", i.e. there is an empty second column in all lines after the header (two consecutive `\t` after the ID).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the format of your `bla.tsv` is already correct with an empty second column, there is only a minimal modification to your approach necessary:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){$2=a[$1]} 1' FS="," hub.csv FS="\t" bla.tsv > result.tsv
```

This will, when processing `bla.tsv`, check if the ID has a matching `hub` value in the array `a`. If so, it sets the second field to that value, an in general, print the current line (including all modifications made).

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @jasmine_hubs You're welcome. There was nothing wrong with the first formulation, but sometimes persons which are unfamiliar with the `awk` syntax can be confused by conditions for rule blocks that contain whitespace (and the `<bla> in <blub>` construct is an unusual sight if you are accustomed to C-style programming). Since we try to write answers for as wide an audience as possible, I thought it might be easier to grasp for future readers if I placed that condition in parentheses.